# Open a local path of webside from Javascript at opening

Tags: html

When I visit my html file, I want to run a Javascript function that can find out the day of the week and then open a certain sub-page of my project.

Comment: can you give more details or maybe what you have tried so far?

Comment: I heard something about API's, I searched a bit about this topic, but did not found anything like a "Day of Week" API. I try the answer maybe this will work.
Thanks for your efford.

Comment: To get good answers, you need to ask good questions. Please check out this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can archive this, when you just add to your html head.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

In this in your Javascript file:

```
var Date = new Date(); // Get the date

var Day = Date.getDay(); // Day of week 0=Sunday; 1=Monday; ....


if(Day == 0) window.location.href = "[local link]";
...
```